# Overload resolution issue for generic method with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, overload-resolution

A code sample:

```
interface IFoo { }
class FooImpl : IFoo { }

static void Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)
    where T : IFoo
{
}

static void Bar<T>(T source)
    where T : IFoo
{
}
```

Can anybody explain, why this method call:

```
var value = new FooImpl[0];
Bar(value);
```

targets `Bar<T>(T source)` (and, hence, doesn't compile)?

Does compiler take into account type parameter constraints at all, when resolving overloads?

**UPD**.

To avoid confusion with arrays. This happens with any implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`, e.g.:

```
var value = new List<FooImpl>();
```

**UPD 2**.

@ken2k mentioned covariance.
But let's forget about `FooImpl`. This:

```
var value = new List<IFoo>();
Bar(value);
```

produces the same error.
I'm sure, that implicit conversion between `List<IFoo>` and `IEnumerable<IFoo>` exists, since I can easily write something like this:

```
static void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<IFoo> sequence) {}
```

and pass `value` into it:

```
SomeMethod(value);
```

Comment: just checked, Bar<IFoo>(value) is accepted.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee: in fact, I want to understand, what prevents compiler to target `Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)` without any additional hints. At first look, there's nothing for preventing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does compiler take into account type parameter constraints at all, when resolving overloads?

No, because generic constraints are not part of the function signature.  You can verify this by adding a `Bar` overload that is identical except for the generic constraints:

```
interface IBar { }

static void Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)
    where T : IFoo
{
}

static void Bar<T>(T source)
    where T : IBar
{
    // fails to compile : Type ____ already defines a member called 'Bar' with the same parameter types
}
```

The reason your code doesn't compile is because the compiler chooses the "best" match based on the method signature, *then* tries to apply the generic constraints.

One possible reason why it *doesn't* is because this call would be ambiguous:

{suppose `List<T>` had an `Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> source`) method}

```
List<object> junk = new List<object>();
junk.Add(1);   // OK
junk.Add("xyzzy") // OK
junk.Add(new [] {1, 2, 3, 4});  //ambiguous - do you intend to add the _array_ or the _contents_ of the array?
```

The obvious fix is to use a different name for the `Bar` method that takes a collection (as is done in the BCL with `Add` and `AddRange`.

Comment: Another fix is to specify what the `T` parameter is, using `Bar<IFoo>(value);`

Comment: "generic constraints are not part of the function signature" - true, unfortunately... just typed similar sample.

Comment: *No, because generic constraints are not part of the function signature.* -- as of c# 7.3 this is no longer true.  Added an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361089/3744182) indicating as such.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Ok, the reason why `Bar<T>(T source)` is selected over `Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)` when passing an List is because of the "`7.5.3.2 Better function member`" section of the C# language reference. What it says is that when an overload resolution must occur, the arguments types are matched to the parameters types of the applicable function members (section 7.5.3.1) and the better function member is selected by the following set of rules:

> • for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
>
> • for at least one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is better than the conversion from EX to QX.

(PX being the parameter types of the first method, QX of the second one)

This rule is applied **"after expansion and type argument substitution"**. Since type argument substitution will swap the Bar(T source) to Bar>(IList source), this method arguments will be a better match than the Bar(IEnumerable source) which needs a conversion.

I couldn't find a online version of the language reference, but you can read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

---

EDIT: misunderstood the question initially, working on finding the correct answer in the c# language spec. Basically IIRC the method is selected by considering the most appropriate type, and if you don't cast your parameter to `IEnumerable<>` exactly, then the `Bar<T>(T source)` will match the parameter type exactly, just like in this sample:

```
public interface ITest { }
public class Test : ITest { }

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test(new Test() ); // outputs "anything" because Test is matched to any type T before ITest
    Console.ReadLine();
}


public static void test<T>(T anything)
{
    Console.WriteLine("anything");
}

public static void test(ITest it)
{
    Console.WriteLine("it");
}
```

Will link to it when found

---

Because the cast between an array and an enumerable must be explicit: this compiles

```
var value = new FooImpl[0].AsEnumerable();
Bar(value);
```

and so does this:

```
var value = new FooImpl[0] as IEnumerable<IFoo>;
Bar(value);
```

From [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection, and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result,
>   the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the
>   Array class.

So your compiler doesn't know that the array matches the signature for Bar, and you have to explicitly cast it

Comment: Is there a problem with the answer, why the downvote?

Comment: The same problem occurs if List<FooImpl> is passed. Though, I am not the downvoter

Comment: @samy: this is very doubtful assumption. First, as Victor mentioned, the same thing will occur with any other implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`. The second, I have no idea, how does my question correlates with the link you provided.

Comment: Dennis, the link explains why an array would not be accepted as a IEnumerable in Bar, but @VictorMukherjee's comment explicits the problem

Answer (score 1):

As of **c# 7.3**, generic constraints are now considered part of the method signature for the purpose of overload resolution.  From [What's new in C# 7.0 through C# 7.3: Improved overload candidates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#improved-overload-candidates):

> 2. When a method group contains some generic methods whose type arguments do not satisfy their constraints, these members are removed from the candidate set.

Thus in [c# 7.3 / .Net Core 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) and later, the code shown in the question **compiles and runs successfully**, and `Bar<T>(IEnumerable<T> value)` is called as desired.

- A demo .Net 5 fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AhcAfc) now compiles successfully
- A demo .NET Framework 4.7.3 fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KBxghG) still fails to compile with the error:

  > `The type 'FooImpl[]' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TestClass.Bar<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'FooImpl[]' to 'IFoo'.`

Answer (score 0):

That's a [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) issue. `List<T>` is not covariant, so there is no implicit conversion between `List<FooImpl>` and `List<IFoo>`.

On the other hand, starting from C# 4, `IEnumerable<T>` now supports covariance, so this works:

```
var value = Enumerable.Empty<FooImpl>();
Bar(value);

var value = new List<FooImpl>().AsEnumerable();
Bar(value);

var value = new List<FooImpl>();
Bar((IEnumerable<IFoo>)value);
```

Comment: Interesting point, but what about if we'll forget about `FooImpl`? I'll update the question soon.