# The compiler matches an extension for which the where clause excludes it

Tags: c#, .net-core, extension-methods

Given the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CompileError
{
    public interface IMessage
    {
        string UniqueId { get; }
    }

    public class Message : IMessage
    {
        public Message(string uniqueId)
        {
            this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        }

        public string UniqueId { get; }
    }

    public static partial class IMessageExtensions
    {
        public static void LogInformation<TMessage>(this TMessage message, string information)
            where TMessage : IMessage
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{message.UniqueId}] {information}");
        }        
    }

    public static partial class ILoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void LogMessage<TMessage>(this ILogger logger, TMessage message)
            where TMessage : IMessage
        {
            // This line does not compile
            logger.LogInformation($"[{message.UniqueId}]");
            // But this one does
            logger.LogInformation($"[{message.UniqueId}]", 42);
            // At least, there's a workaround:
            LoggerExtensions.LogInformation(logger, $"[{message.UniqueId}]");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler fails on the first call to `LogInformation` in `LogMessage`, as it thinks I'm calling `TMessage.LogInformation` defined above, instead of `LoggerExtensions.LogInformation` from the MS package.

I thought the `where` clause was enough to tell the compiler not to use this extension. Obviously, there are workarounds, as shown. I can also make sure they don't share namespaces and the wrong `LogInformation`'s namespace is not visible from `LogMessage`, but I was surprised this could not be addressed by a C# compiler. Bug?

Comment: Can you please show the `TMessage` class?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26037469/5311735. Long story short - where constraints do not participate in overload resolution, at all.