# Same method signature confusion

Tags: c#, nullable

Assuming C# 8.0 and reference type nullability, why are these signatures considered equal:

```
void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : class
void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : struct
```

but these are not?

```
void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : class
void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : struct
```

The only thing different is the nullability of enumerable elements.

Comment: Err... Struct are considered value types, and by definition can't be null right?

Comment: I assume this is C# 8?

Comment: Type constraints aren't used for overload resolution.  They are checked *after* overload resolution.  I think this is a duplicate of [Overload resolution issue for generic method with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037469/overload-resolution-issue-for-generic-method-with-constraints)

Comment: `T?` when `T` is a `struct` is `Nullable<T>`, which is distinguishable from any class `T`. (Note that this works whether you use `T` or `T?`, NRTs aren't strictly relevant in this case and of course `T` and `T?` with `T` a `class` are "the same" type from a runtime perspective.) For the `T` case it's the well-known problem that [constraints aren't used in overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26037469/4137916).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you, that does actually make sense. If you want you can put that comment up as answer and I'll chose it.

Comment: @Any Don't think that's a good dupe target. Note the code presented here works differently in C#8 vs C#7.

Comment: @DavidG Okay, sorry about that.  I misinterpreted OPs comment.  I thought they were referring to the dupe target when they said "that does make sense, if you put that up, I'll accept it and close".  My bad.  I *really* dislike being able to unilaterally close questions.

Comment: @Amy Hey, it's all fine, I don't mind the hammer, we just have to be careful when using it. I get it wrong too.