# create overload extension method where parameter implements additional interface

Tags: c#

I currently have a library function I am using which is:

```cs
public SqlExpression<From> CreateQuery<From, Into>(IQueryDb<From, Into> dto)
{
    //...
}
```

Which I call like:

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto);
```

Object `dto` implements interface `IQueryDb<From, Into>`.  What I want to do is to create an extension method overload that will be used instead of this method if the `dto` object also implements the interface `IDevExtremeQuery` as well as `IQueryDb<From, Into>`.

Is this possible?

I tried creating this method:

```cs
public static SqlExpression<From> CreateQuery<From, Into, T>(this IAutoQueryDb autoQuery, T dto) where T : IQueryDb<From, Into>, IDevExtremeQuery
{
    //...
}
```

But that doesn't work.  My goal is to alter behaviour of this method for all DTO that implement the additional interface.  What is best way to go about this?

Here is standalone repro:

```cs
using System;

namespace InterfaceOverload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var aq = new AutoQuery();
            
            Console.WriteLine(aq.CreateQuery(new Dto1()).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(aq.CreateQuery(new Dto2()).Value); //should output from extension as it also implements additional interface
        }
    }

    public class Dto1 : IQueryDb<object, object> { }

    public class Dto2 : IQueryDb<object, object>, IDevExtremeQuery { }

    public interface IAutoQueryDb
    {
        SqlExpression<From> CreateQuery<From, Into>(
            IQueryDb<From, Into> dto);
    }
    public interface IQueryDb<From, Into> { }

    public interface IDevExtremeQuery { }

    public class SqlExpression<T>
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class AutoQuery : IAutoQueryDb
    {
        public SqlExpression<From> CreateQuery<From, Into>(IQueryDb<From, Into> dto)
        {
            return new SqlExpression<From>() {Value = "This is from Autoquery"};
        }
    }

    public static class AutoQueryExtensions
    {
        public static SqlExpression<From> CreateQuery<From, Into, T>(this IAutoQueryDb autoQuery, T dto) where T : IQueryDb<From, Into>, IDevExtremeQuery
        {
            return new SqlExpression<From>() { Value = "This is from Extension" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recreating all of these interfaces to run a sample app is extremely difficult.  Can you post a concise, complete reproduction of what you've tried that outlines exactly what is not working?

Comment: Don't think you can do that via a constraint.  See [Overload resolution issue for generic method with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26037469/3744182): *Does compiler take into account type parameter constraints at all, when resolving overloads?  No, because generic constraints are not part of the function signature.*

Comment: @dbc correct, although what the OP has posted isn't strictly an overload.  Without a more complete example, it is nearly impossible to tell what it is doing.

Comment: But wait, that answer might be obsolete!  From [What's new in C# 7.0 through C# 7.3: Improved overload candidates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#improved-overload-candidates): *When a method group contains some generic methods whose type arguments do not satisfy their constraints, these members are removed from the candidate set.*

Comment: OK that makes sense.  If constraints do not alter method signature this approach wont work.  I will try to make a stand alone reproduction to show actual issue.

Comment: I have added standalone repro.  Trying to get alternative method to fire when dto has additonal interface

Comment: From [Binding Extension Methods at Compile Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#binding-extension-methods-at-compile-time): *You can use extension methods to extend a class or interface, but not to override them. An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface or class method will never be called. At compile time, extension methods always have lower priority than instance methods defined in the type itself.*  So I don't think you can use an extension method in the way you want.

Comment: Is there any alternative approach that might work?

Comment: You could use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that wrap the underlying object in a `IQueryDb<object, object>, IDevExtremeQuery` decorator that overrides the appropriate methods while forwarding everything else to the underlying original object?

Comment: hmm, so my DTO would be a class that inherits from a class that implements IQueryDb<object, object>, IDevExtremeQuery.  So this would let me have signature for the new type.  Yes, I think that would work, thanks.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.  If I create a child class the class still has IQueryDb interface so even though my extension targets the new class type, the original method fires as it matches the interface.